# Fading background image slideshow (in jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to get a fading background image slideshow, but I can't seem to find a way to get it the background images to cross-fade into eachother. Instead, I get a flash of white screen, followed by the next image. I've tried `.animate`, `.fadeOut`... none of which worked.

**Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNSFL/) of what I have.**

I'm thinking I can maybe do something with loading the next image as a background image behind the first, and somehow magically fade out the first, à la

```
background:url(images/pattern.png) repeat, url(FIRST IMAGE) no-repeat center center fixed,url(SECOND IMAGE) no-repeat center center fixed";
```

followed by the magical fading code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions weren't working on `html` or `body` tags, so I made a wrapping `div` tag (which can go inside body) and it works fine now.

You can see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BNSFL/4/

Comment: Thanks so much! If anyone is curious, I got it to cross-fade: http://jsfiddle.net/BNSFL/7/